# How to refactroing js object's attributs in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, refactoring

I use the Refactor function of vscode to rename the variable name. I found that there is no problem with the smart modification of the global variable or the local variable, but the property of the object does not take effect. Is there any method or extension that can do this?

Vscode info:
Version: 1.36.1 (user setup)
Submit: 2213894ea0415ee8c85c5eea0d0ff81ecc191529
Date: 2019-07-08T22:59:35.033Z
Electron: 4.2.5
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18922

```
g = se.prototype;
g.eb = function (a) {
    this.pf = this.Sr(); //this.Sr will be refactored
    a = this.cu(a);
    return Pc(a, null)
};
g.au = function (a) {
    this.pf && "*" == this.Me && (a.id = this.pf)
};
g.Tt = function (a) {
    if (!this.zi)
        return a;
    a = de("<div>" + a + "</div>");
    he(a);
    return a.innerHTML
};
g.Sr = function () { //want to smart rename the g.Sr to g.sanitizer
    var a = !("STYLE" in this.Pe) && "STYLE" in this.Qe;
    return "*" == this.Me && a ? "sanitizer-" + (Math.floor(2147483648 * Math.random()).toString(36) + Math.abs(Math.floor(2147483648 * Math.random()) ^ Ja()).toString(36)) : this.Me
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code's built-in JavaScript IntelliSense is not able to understand that code, which is why rename does not work. The code relies a lot on dynamic behavior such as assigning `g` to `se.prototype` and then further writing properties on to `g`. The IntelliSense engine just can't understand that `this.Sr` inside `eb` refers to the same `g.Sr` below (it's also not obvious what is going on to a programmer at first glance either)

You can investigate this by hovering over various variables in your source. If the hover information shows `any`, it means that the  VS Code IntelliSense engine cannot properly infer what type the variable is so semantic operations like rename will not work. You can also add [`// @ts-check`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript) to the top of your file to enable some basic type checking of your code

For the existing snippet however, your best bet is to do a text based find/replace.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I can understand that this dynamic behavior of js is the root cause. JavaScript IntelliSense is not smart enough, I hope it can become smarter.